# Is there a reason $⊑$ in CSP is analogous to $⊇$ (as opposed to $⊆$)?

Tags: terminology, computer-science, language

The 'square' subset symbols are sometimes used to express [analogous concepts to subsets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569400/does-sqsubset-have-any-special-meaning), like prefixes or suffixes.

However their use in [CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes) seems to be counterintuitive to their shape: $⊑$ appears analogous to $⊇$ (as opposed to the more similar looking $⊆$):

> A process $P$ refines $Q$, denoted as $Q⊑_TP$, iff $traces(P) ⊆ traces(Q)$.

Does Hoare explain anywhere why he chose this orientation of the symbol?

Comment: Maybe my browser isn't rendering well, but I don't see that symbol on the Wikipedia page.  Did you quote from some other source?